# Python: Using bottle with Tornado web server to handle concurrent connections

Tags: python, concurrency, tornado, bottle, python-multithreading

I'm new to Python and web technologies, I am currently building a web service that uses bottle framework. But I found out that the requests to my server actually interfere with each other, i.e when multiple requests are running concurrently, they all get significantly slow.
After rounds of searching, it turned out to me that bottle actually has other server options (such as tornado) to handle concurrent connections when the load increases: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#server-options

But the documentation does mention much about the actual implementation. So my question is, how to handle concurrent connections using bottle in conjunction with Tornado?
Any degree of help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: does installing tornado then running your bottle app with `bottle.run(server='tornado')` work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but does this really do it? I mean I have been using this simple implementation(server='tornado'), but when I ran multiple intensive requests they both get even slower, so I thought maybe there is supposed to be some specific way to handle concurrent connections so that each request doesn't interfere one another.

Comment: I would try one of the multi threaded python servers.  This would allow you to handle multiple requests at one time.  Tornado is asyncronous but it is single threaded, i think the same blocking issues that you have with bottle server will be present with tornado, since your code is (i'm guessing) not asynchronous

Answer (score 2):

You can try with different backends using [this](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/deployment.html#switching-the-server-backend) list. Instead of tornado, pasteserver could be a good choice. If this doesn't work you can try with apache. The ref should explain how.